# Why does (new) Admob attempt to cast my custom mediation adapter to the old version?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have had some apps on the market for quite some time, but for the last few years I have not really done any maintenance on the apps, and back when I did interstitial ads were not available for all (or maybe it was but I just didnt know how to).

Getting some more spare time on my hands again, I would like to pick up and improve the old apps while also beginning to work on some new ideas.

The monetization on the existing apps are through Admob only with no mediation, and to be honest looking at the numbers (impressions fx) I think using some mediation and other networks would indeed increase the income a bit. For this reason I am trying to learn more about mediation.

I have found a few interesting ad networks and using the sdks and adapters with these Admob integrated networks seems to work pretty good, however I also see some interesting networks where some custom classes must be created in order to support these, which should not be any problem.

I found some guides and created my class implementing com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventBanner and creating the code for getting ads from the network. When running the code I see in logcat that the result is an exception (ClassCastException) as Admob is trying to cast the class to the "old" version of CustomEventBanner.

All ad related code in the project uses the new sdk (com.google.android.gms.*), but for some reason it still tries to cast the CustomEventBanner class as the old version.

Stacktrace (relevant part):

```
08-15 23:30:06.730    3875-3875/com.xxx.xxx.xxxW/Ads﹕ Could not request banner ad from adapter.
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.CustomEventBannerTest cannot be cast to com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventBanner
at com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventAdapter.requestBannerAd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventAdapter.requestBannerAd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ca.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.bv$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
...
```

**Note**: I do have a working solution which is just implementing both the old and the new interface for CustomEventBanner with the methods, which is working fine, but I am really interested in knowing why this is happening, as I would prefer not to reference old sdk code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the SDK. You're going to have to refer to the old APIs until it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.. Does this mean we cannot use the CustomEventBanner ? for using networks that are not directly supported by google-admob ?

Comment: contactmeandroid > What we have done is just creating a separate adapter class for each network we want to support. This class will then implement both the "old" and "new" CustomEventBanner and its methods. Currently only the old is used, however I guess the new will be used at some point, and when that happens the class will still fetch ads from the network.